# Makefile with chained rules runs last command needlessly on each run

Tags: makefile

I use TikZ to draw all kinds of vector graphics for my documents. It is rather slow and each drawing makes the compilation time of the main LaTeX document longer. Therefore I have all the figures as standalone files. They are compiled independently and the PDF file is included in the main document. This allows for parallel LaTeX runs on an as-needed basis.

The process looks as follows:

- The actual TikZ code is in a LaTeX snippet file at `Figures/fig.tex`. A Python script (`tikzpicture_wrap.py`) will wrap the snippet into a standalone document including preamble. This files goes into `build/page/fig.tex`.
- `lualatex` is run on the file `build/page/fig.tex` which produces `build/page/fig.pdf`.
- As I use the same document class (`scrartcl`) as for the same document, the figure is set on A4 paper and therefore needs to be cropped before I can include it in the document. For that I use `pdfcrop` as a last step. The result is put into `build/fig.pdf`

My complete makefile looks like this:

```
# Copyright © 2015-2016 Martin Ueding <dev@martin-ueding.de>

.PRECIOUS: %.tex %.pdf build/page/%.pdf

document_tex := $(wildcard physics*.tex)
document_pdf := $(document_tex:%.tex=%.pdf)

figures_tex := $(wildcard Figures/*.tex)
figures_pdf := $(figures_tex:Figures/%.tex=build/%.pdf)

all: $(figures_pdf)
#all: $(document_pdf)  # Disabled to only typeset figures right now.

test:
    @echo "document:    $(document_pdf)"
    @echo "figures_tex: $(figures_tex)"
    @echo "figures_pdf: $(figures_pdf)"

$(document_pdf): $(figures_pdf)

$(figures_pdf): build

build:
    mkdir -p build/page

build/page/%.tex: Figures/%.tex
    ../build-system/tikzpicture_wrap.py $< $@

build/%.pdf: build/page/%.pdf
    pdfcrop $< $@
    touch $@  # Added in an attempt to work around the problem, does not make any difference, though.

%.pdf: %.tex
    cd $$(dirname $@) && lualatex --halt-on-error $$(basename $<)

clean:
    $(RM) *-blx.bib
    $(RM) *.aux
    $(RM) *.log
    $(RM) *.run.xml
    $(RM) *.out
    $(RM) *.svg
    $(RM) *.pdf
    $(RM) -r build
```

It does work, it typesets all figures and they end up at `build/*.pdf`. The problem is that the `pdfcrop` step is run again and again, even when there is nothing more to do. In the output you can see the following:

```
pdfcrop build/page/propagator.pdf build/propagator.pdf
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
==> 1 page written on `build/propagator.pdf'.
touch build/propagator.pdf
```

This is repeated for every single figure I have in my `Figures` directory.

I thought that this might be a problem with [chained rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules) and added the intermediate file to the `.PRECIOUS` target for make to keep it. Now the files used by `pdfcrop` are not deleted midway.

Next I thought that it might be a problem with the timestamps on the files. If the source is newer than the target, make will run it. Therefore I added the `touch` to make sure that the target was newer than the source. This is not a problem as can be seen here after the run I did this morning. I did not change anything in that Figure since yesterday.

The source file. `stat Figures/propagator.tex`:

```
  File: 'Figures/propagator.tex'
  Size: 102             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 17432618    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      mu)   Gid: ( 1000/      mu)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2016-01-16 10:58:34.384515470 +0100
Modify: 2016-01-16 10:58:34.369515566 +0100
Change: 2016-01-16 10:58:34.373515540 +0100
 Birth: -
```

The typeset PDF document. `stat build/page/propagator.pdf`:

```
  File: 'build/page/propagator.pdf'
  Size: 6265            Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 17432636    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      mu)   Gid: ( 1000/      mu)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2016-01-16 10:59:04.317323576 +0100
Modify: 2016-01-16 10:59:04.261323935 +0100
Change: 2016-01-16 10:59:04.261323935 +0100
 Birth: -
```

The cropped final file. `stat build/propagator.pdf`:

```
  File: 'build/propagator.pdf'
  Size: 6612            Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd03h/64771d    Inode: 17301550    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      mu)   Gid: ( 1000/      mu)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2016-01-17 09:54:32.102511429 +0100
Modify: 2016-01-17 09:54:30.943517396 +0100
Change: 2016-01-17 09:54:30.943517396 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Still it performs all the `pdfcrop` operations again and again. I do not understand why. For the meantime I added the following kludge to make the compilation process finish a bit faster when there is nothing to do:

```
build/%.pdf: build/page/%.pdf
    if [ $< -nt $@ ]; then \
        pdfcrop $< $@; \
        fi
```

What is the actual problem here and how can I solve it?

Comment: I do not fully understand. Suppose that `Figures/` contains three files. Is it the case that you wish `pdfcrop` to run once, but it runs three times? Or that you wish it to run three times but it runs nine times? Or that it runs three times when only one file in `Figures/` has been changed recently?

Comment: In the case of three files in `Figures/` I want `pdfcrop` to run three times in total on the first run. After that I want `pdfcrop` to not be run at all as there is nothing to do. However, make always invokes it for each figure there is. So it is the last of your suggestions except that it runs three times even if there is no change at all.

Comment: If I undestand makefile correctly, it has every `build/%.pdf` target dependent both from `build/page/%.pdf` and from `build`, which is not related with particular file. So, `build` target is always treated as out-of-date and is always built, and so `build/%.pdf` target is always built too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tsyvarev is on the right track.  This is indeed the problem:

```
$(figures_pdf): build
```

However, it's not because *`build` is not related to a particular file*.  `build` *does* exist: it's a directory which is created with the rule:

```
build:
        mkdir -p build/page
```

This builds the subdirectory `build/page`, which means that `build` exists (as a directory) and so in subsequent builds when make checks to see if it exists, it will determine that yes, it does.  Make doesn't treat directories any different than any other file, when listed as a target.

However the existence of a prerequisite is not the only test that make uses: it also checks to see if the prerequisite is newer than the target.  This is where directories and files behave differently, and why you virtually never (except in some special cases) want to use a directory as a normal prerequisite of a target.

A directory has a "time last modified" just like a file, and a directory's TLM value is updated just like a file's: when the directory is modified.  What constitutes "modifying" a directory?  Well, adding a new file, deleting an existing file, or renaming a file all modify the directory and cause it's TLM to change.

Probably you can see your problem now: every time your makefile adds, removes, or renames a file in the `build` directory its modification time is updated.  This means that the directory `build` is always newer than almost all the files in it, which means they always rebuild every time.

There are two ways to work around this.  One is to just always create the directory as a side-effect; remove `build` from the prerequisite list and remove the rule above, and instead simply force the directory to be created by make when it parses the makefile:

```
__dummy := $(shell mkdir -p build/page)
```

The second way, if you have a sufficiently new version of GNU make, is to use [order-only prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html):

```
$(figures_pdf): | build
```

Comment: Spot on! The `| build` fixed the problem completely. Thanks for this very precise answer!